# Used code bought on internet to unlock Galaxy S3 from 3 UK to O2-UK. Will rooting the device harm it?

Tags: rooting, sim-unlocking

My Galaxy S3 was locked to 3-UK when I got it.  So I used a code I bought on the internet to unlock it.  When buying the code the form asked which network I wanted to unlock the handset for.  I said O2-UK as that's the SIM I want to use.  No other SIM cards work on the handset except 3 and O2.  If I root my handset will O2-UK still work on it?  Thanks to anyone that can help.

Answer (score 1):

Rooting the phone won't change SIM-lock settings, they're saved in a separate part of the phone, please see these previous questions for more info on that: [Where are the SIM Lock settings stored on an Android phone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5709/where-are-the-sim-lock-settings-stored-on-an-android-phone)  and [Does Unlocking bootloader affect network lock?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/23309/does-unlocking-bootloader-affect-network-lock)

You can find more explaining these different terminologies here: [What is the difference between: Rooting, Jailbreak, ROM, Mod, etc.?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2885/what-is-the-difference-between-rooting-jailbreak-rom-mod-etc)